# Is there a way to trigger a "folder open" from Sublime Text 3 API?

Tags: sublimetext3, sublime-text-plugin

I working on a plugin which will generate some file and I need to prompt the user somehow so that he selects a folder where these files will be generated.

Is there a way to do this with Sublime Text 3 API?

Comment: If you are familliar with python maybe you can adapt [this plugin](https://github.com/csch0/SublimeText-File-Navigator) to your needs.

Answer (score 1):

Probably the most straightforward way would be to open an input box ([`sublime.show_input_panel()`](http://www.sublimetext.com/docs/3/api_reference.html#sublime.Window)) with a default value and allow the user to enter their own path if desired.

If you were using the standard Python 3 distribution from python.org, you could always use something like [`tkinter.tix.DirSelectDialog()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/tkinter.tix.html#tkinter.tix.DirSelectDialog) or `tkinter.filedialog`, but the stripped-down version of Python 3.3.3 shipped with Sublime Text 3 does not include several modules, including `tkinter`. If a graphical interface is important to you, you may want to consider including a small GUI toolkit like [easygui](http://pythonhosted.org/easygui/) with your plugin.

Comment: EasyGUI is built on top of Tk so I might as well just use Tk. Any idea if I could bundle Tk with my Sublime Plugin?

Comment: @daniels Ah, I didn't realize that. Makes sense, though. The reason you almost never see ST plugins with GUI elements outside of what Sublime provides is because most frameworks (Tkinter included) contain platform-specific compiled code, since a pure-Python GUI would be darn near impossible to write. That means if you want to distribute your plugin you'd need separate versions for all 3 supported platforms - Windows, OS X, and Linux.